# How to read local Storage JSON in angular index.html file and show in View page source as a script

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-universal, angular-local-storage

I have JSON in my localStorage which I want to read in my angular index.html file and also I want to show this JSON when I see the View page source. Below code, I have tried.
Note: When I am seeing View page source then only Plain HTML is showing noting dynamic from localStorage.

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
      alert(JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('profileJson'))));
      var data = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('profileJson')))
      var nameFromJson = data.default.provider.name
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = nameFromJson;

    }
  </script>
  <p id="demo"></p>

  <app-root></app-root> 

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

View page source only gets the raw HTML then displays it.  Therefore, you wouldn't be able to access the local storage when you're getting that text out because it would require JavaScript to be run.

Comment: Is there is anyway available to see Local Storage JSON data when I View the page source in the angular application?

Comment: No, angular ends up just shipping vanilla JS so it would not be possible.